# Get value from select box to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm new at programming in MVC, so I ran into this problem...

I have the following selectBox:

```
<select class="span5" id="selectBox">
<option>Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

How do I get the selected value into a model?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: So there isn't a way?

Comment: It would be nice if you provided your controller action and what your form looked like. *However*, one basic thing you are missing is a name on the select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating your select list in a ViewModel:

```
public class whatever {

   public List<SelectListItem> MonthList {get;set;}
   public string SelectedMonth {get;set;}

   public whatever()
   {
      MonthList = new List<SelectListItem>();
      MonthList.Add(new SelectListItem{
         Text = "January",
         Value = "January"
      });
   }
}
```

Then in your view you can just use the drop down razor helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMonth, Model.MonthList)
```

When you submit your page the selected option will automatically get picked up.